Si stanno tessendo barriere alla partecipazione in questa comunità?
Su questo post ho letto di uno studio che si è fatto su Stack Overflow in cui si sono riscontrati fatti come 

More specifically, we find significant gender gaps in activity: women are more likely to ask questions, while men provide more answers and cast more votes.

Curioso. Mi chiedo se a qualcuno dispiaccia il fatto che esitano queste donne che pongono queste domande (è una domanda retorica). Comunque, ho l'impressione che non ce ne siano molte, di donne, su Italian.SE... (potrei sbagliarmi: su Internet non si sa mai).
E anche

Stack Overflow is itself a well-studied platform. Vasilescu et al. show that women are underrepresented in this community (Vasilescu et al. 2013). Interviews with a sample of Stack Overflow users highlight the barriers women have to greater participation. Women respondents listed the lack of awareness of some site features, the intimidating community size and their fear of lacking adequate qualifications as main barriers to participation (Ford et al. 2016).

Italian.SE è una comunità molto più piccola di Stack Overflow, dunque il suo comportamento può essere diverso di quello descritto sopra.
Tuttavia, oggi, 8 marzo, giornata internazionale dei diritti della donna, mi piacerebbe invitarvi a riflettere sulla possibilità che queste barriere alla partecipazione esistano anche sul nostro sito.
Personalmente, nei più di 5 anni che ci ho stato partecipando, non avevo mai avuto l'impressione che ci fossero. Magari ce ne sono state e non me ne sono accorta. Forse di qualcosina sì, nel modo in cui sono stati scritti certi commenti, ma sono convinta che non fosse intenzionato. Negli ultimi 15 giorni, però, ho percepito per la prima volta, in modo molto evidente, la volontà di tessere queste barriere (ovviamente, questo è una mia opinione).
Comincio col dire che, come donna e, per di più, non italiana, in questo giorno vi chiedo di concedermi il diritto di poter scegliere le mie domande liberamente, senza coazioni, inclusa questa mia domanda sul sito Meta.
In questi ultimi 15 giorni sono stata severamente assalita da commenti in cui mi si diceva insistententemente di non porre tante domande perché facendo così (e facendo forse altre cose che non so quali siano) monopolizzo il sito, di cercarmi le risposte da sola, di non imbarcarmi o non perdermi in sottigliezze, di non chiedere su temi peculiari che interessano a pochi, di porre domande generali che potrebbero dare un consiglio a una non madrelingua che mostra lacune, di capire che il problema è molte domande con una certa caratteristica, di chiedere "che significa X in questo contesto?" poche volte perché se non smetto di farlo con tanta frequenza la cosa balza all'occhio, di non porre domande poco sincere (non idea su cosa possa significare questo), di non fare monologhi scrivendo risposte a domande che io stessa avevo posto in passato (parecchie di tre, quattro anni fa o forse anche di più), di non mostrare un percorso che io abbia compiuto per curiosità perché ad altri utenti interessa meno di meno (in relazione a queste mie auto-risposte), di non scrivere una domanda a una mia risposta dopo che qualcun altro l'ha fatto perché può dare l'idea di voler correggere o insegnare come vanno fatte bene le risposte (non te ne sei accorta che il motore del sito chiede "sei sicuro di volerti autorispondere?"?), di non scrivere risposte che recitano nel modo messo tra parentesi ("come riportato dal Garzanti [LINK], il significato è blablabla [sostanzialmente una ripetizione di ciò che dice la fonte]") perché possono dare la vaga impressione di dire "vedi, la fonte è lì a disposizione di tutti, ma io l'ho trovata, e tu no. Io sono più bravo di te, la prossima volta cerca meglio, io ho anche altro da fare" e perché non riportano alcunché di originale e di ragionato o per lo meno diretto a chi ha posto la domanda, di non scrivere risposte citando parecchie fonti perché se si chiede a un grande esperto "questa cosa, secondo te, è bella o brutta" non si ha piacere che la sua grande cultura venga sfoggiata per dire "caio dice che è bella, tizio dice che è brutta, sempronio è critico con i primi due", di non scrivere risposte basandomi soltanto in quello che dicono fonti autorevoli senza aggiungere del proprio perché tali fonti potrebbero essere sbagliate per diversi motivi e allora la responsabilità caderà su di me e perché questo significa anche dire "non posso avere torto, lo dice lui" o perché si può dare l'impressione di qualificare qualcosa come indiscutibile citando il Garzanti ma potrebbe accadere che Garzanti non sia l'unico a pensarla a quel modo, di non citare nelle mie risposte soltanto libri colti scritti magari secoli fa  perché allora il sito diventa calloso, 
di dovermi concentrare su fondamenti come la differenza tra "quelli" e "quegli", di non citare definizioni di dizionari nelle mie domande perché la semantica e specie la connotazione non si risolvono con i dizionari, di porre domande a un livello che possa migliorare le mie conoscenze della lingua, di non esseguire procedimenti nelle mie domande che non funzionano a livello scientifico, di non porre domande (come qualche mia domanda è stata giudicata) che richiedano una padronanza eccellente dello spagnolo in tutte le sue sfumature da parte di chi voglia rispondere con l'intenzione di fornire una risposta adeguata, di cercare di riformulare una mia domanda in inglese perché così com'è sarebbe la tipica domanda degna di un downvote per mancanza di comprensibilità (riferito a una mia domanda su una traduziine dallo spagnolo, ma perlomeno questa volta ho potuto sapere la ragione del voto negativo)...  E altre cose che in questo momento preferisco dimenticare, per cui non le riporto qui.
Alcuni di questi commenti mi sono arrivati in due o tre versioni, ripetendo le stesse cose leggermente modificate, a volte in intervalli di dieci minuti. E alcune di queste cose sono state scritte in una risposta su questo sito Meta riguardo alla quale mi si è detto in un commento che meriterebbe un +1 per bilanciare il mio voto negativo, cioè, dicendomi che non avrei dovuto votare negativamente, negandomi il diritto di non essere d'accordo con le idee espresse lì.
L'unico modo di porre fine a quest'incubo, a questa tortura è stato smettere di postare domande (e anche risposte) sul sito. Precedentemente, ho cercato di farlo in un'altra maniera, sbagliandomi nel modo di agire (sì, quando una persona è sconvolta, a volte non riesce a reagire senza sbagliarsi) e il risultato è stato che mi si è detto in un commento: «Tu non mi vieterai di rispondere a qualsiasi cosa a meno che io abbia compiuto qualche infrazione dimostrabile. Questo non è il TUO sito. Inoltre attientiti a quello che tu detti agli altri. La tua lamentela va chiarificata nel "Meta"», (con "TUO" scritto così, con le maiuscole).
Se tutto questo non è porre una barriera alla partecipazione, non soltanto alla mia partecipazione, anche alla partecipazione di tutti quelli – o quelle – che possano fare le stesse cose che mi sono state così severamente criticate, se non è una barriera, allora, cos'è? Inoltre, se un/un'utente legge qualche commento di tutti quelli che mi sono stati rivolti in questi giorni (per fortuna parecchi sono stati cancellati, certamente non da me), non potrebbe spaventarsi e non tornare mai più?
E non soltanto dei commenti rivolti a me, anche di certi commenti recentemente indirizzati ad altri utenti. Per fare un esempio, a proposito delle risposte a questa domanda, sono apparsi commenti come «If you are here to find some competent support, you must know that this site will not give it to you because it only thrives on conflicts, unfortunately!» rivolto all'OP oppure «The ones who downvoted my answer are invited to provide explanations to the asker unless they want to be considered what they are, that is a whole bunch of incompetent users!». Non credete che l'OP potrebbe essersi spaventato di questa aggressività e aver deciso di non ritornare mai più?
Una cosa si è detta su cui sono d'accordo: la severità nell'esigenza a citare fonti autorevoli in assolutamente tutte le risposte è anche una barriera alla partecipazione. Perché se qualcuno risponde dicendo "sono piemontese, dunque conosco bene questa parola: il suo significato è questo e si usa in tale e tale contesti" e gli si o le si risponde col commento "Hai fonti?", quel/quell'utente non ritorna mai più.
Insomma, votate negativamente le mie domande se credete che è quello che dovete fare, votate per chiuderle se lo ritenete opportuno perché non sono utili, non sono d'interesse o sono incomprensibili tanto è cattivo il mio italiano: non è estremismo (anche questo mi si è detto e immagino che qualcuno pensarà che sto estremizzando di nuovo), sono le regole del gioco. Ma lasciatemi decidere da me stessa, in tutta libertà, le domande che voglio porre sul sito.
Potrei chiedere altro, ma forse sarebbe chiedere troppo.
Credo, però, che qualcuno si sia sbagliato su una cosa (è una mia impressione: potrei andare completamente errata): noi donne siamo forti: dobbiamo per forza esserlo per poter sopravvivere in questa nostra società. 
E scusate una volta in più gli errori del mio cattivo italiano: sentitevi in tutta libertà di correggerli: io non ho più voglia di rileggere tutto questo.

Questa domanda è stata votata per chiudere con la ragione "needs details or clarity" ("Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking").
Bene, cerco di porre le mie domande in modo più chiaro e concreto:

Credete che alcuno dei fatti che ho sopra descritto (non importa che questo sia diretto a me o a un altro utente, non importa il sesso o l'orientamento sessuale di questo utente, né quali conoscenze possa avere sulla lingua; non importa che questo accada qui o su un altro SE; non importa che questo sia accaduto recentemente o che qualcosa simile possa succedere nel futuro) possa derivare in qualche sorta di barriera alla partecipazione?
Riguardo all'«etiquette»
del sito: credete che si dovrebbe cercare di rispettare la libertà di un utente (non importa chi sia) di poter scegliere da sé stesso le domande che vuol porre nel sito, cioè, cercare di non scrivere commenti insistenti (soprattutto quando si tratta di moltissimi commenti insistendo sempre sulla stessa sorta di cose, scritti in un breve periodo di tempo) diretti a questo utente che suppongano   coazioni del tipo che ho descritto sopra (assumendo che questo utente accetta le regole del gioco, cioè, ammette che queste domande possono essere votate negativamente oppure votate per chiudere)?

E, chi creda che non abbia nulla a che vedere, mi 
scusi per quello che ho detto delle donne e della giornata  dell'8 marzo. Credevo di aver chiarito che la possibilità che c'entrasse in qualche modo fosse una mia impressione personale che potrebbe essere completamente errata. 

Personalmente, ho avvertito anch'io un tono blandamente misogino (oltre che xenofobo) in alcuni recenti commenti, non privo del cosiddetto “mansplaining”. La buona notizia, se c'è, è che si tratta di un numero limitatissimo di utenti recenti, mentre anche a me sembra che il grosso dei frequentatori, fissi e occasionali, di questo sito si concentri, magari anche accalorandosi e occasionalmente quasi litigando, sugli argomenti di cui si parla e non su chi ne parla.

Se veramente è stato così, @DaG, questo post sarà il mio piccolo, piccolissimo, insignificante contributo alla giornata dell'8 marzo. Perché, come ho detto in un commento alla risposta di Carla, quelli che sono riprovevoli sono i fatti, non le persone, e non importa che questo accada qui o altrove.

Visto che sono stato chiamato in causa anche io fra altri, sia pure tramite allusione, mi interesserebbe davvero sapere dove ci siano in uno dei mei commenti o in quelli critici di altri, tracce attestabili e non speculative di atteggiamenti misogini. Mi sembra che questo sia uno "strong claim" che non si può lasciare indiscusso.

@Nico, ti è chiara la differenza fra “ho avvertito un tono blandamente...” e “tracce attestabili e non speculative”? Ma soprattutto, conosci l'espressione “coda di paglia”? Io neppure mi ricordavo di chi fossero certi commenti, ma adesso ti ringrazio per la conferma implicita. E ora trolla finché ti pare: non ho intenzione di rispondere.

@DaG Scrivere "ho avvertito un tono blandamente" per sostenere una affermazione altrui con pretese meno blande non è corretto dal punto di vista etico perché è infondato. Se l'hai "avvertito" devi segnalare indizi. Idem dicasi per la xenofobia. Questo non dimostra altro che una tendenza a teorie complottiste. Qui si tratta di spondare accuse davvero forti. Il fatto che tu mi dai del "troll" e mi imputi una "coda di paglia" invece di affrontare una discussione costruttiva la dice più lunga su di te che su di me oltre a essere una risposta offensiva a una semplice domanda di chiarimento

@Nico La mia impressione è che tu abbia uno stile di discussione molto aggressivo. Penso che alcuni punti che sollevi sarebbero meglio accolti se li ponessi più diplomaticamente. Inoltre consiglio di meditare su "excusatio non petita.."

@denis Innanzitutto consiglierei a te di imparare a usare i modi di dire in modo proprio. Io non mi sono scusato o giustificato con nessuno perché non ho nessun motivo per farlo. Ben al contrario, ho chiesto spiegazioni a un'accusa non fondata (quasi tutte le citazioni del post originale si riferiscono a me, cosa ricostrubile per chiunque). Inoltre se tu ravvisi nella mia richiesta obiettiva di spiegazione uno stile aggressivo invece di ravvisare tale stile in espressioni come "trollare" e "coda di paglia", mi fai un enorme favore perché dimostri chiaramente i punti ciechi di questo sistema.

Qualcuno chiedeva dei chiarimenti... Io non usato la parola "xenofobia", ho scritto in un altro commento che molte delle cose che mi sono state dette sono per il fatto di non essere italiana. Un esempio: se un italiano fa una domanda spiegando che sta facendo una traduzione dallo spagnolo, che si è imbattuto nella parola "agobiado" e non sa come tradurla in italiano, non credo gli si risponda col commento (segue)

«Anche se posso parer cattivo, ripeto quello che ho scritto diverse volte: come mai vai a imbarcarti su sottigliezze come questa invece di concentrarti su fondamenti come "quelli utenti" invece di "quegli uitenti"? (sic)».

Un solo commento come questo non è un problema: può sembrare persino ben intenzionato. Il problema è più di 20 commenti come questo in pochi giorni e la risposta «Tu non mi vieterai di rispondere a qualsiasi cosa a meno che io abbia compiuto qualche infrazione dimostrabile. Questo non è il TUO sito. Inoltre attientiti a quello che tu detti agli altri. La tua lamentela va chiarificata nel "Meta"» quando si chiede di non ricevere più questa sorta di commenti.

@Charo Ma infatti la mia risposta era rivolta a DaG che ha usato la parola e non a te. In secondo luogo, forse il tono era un po' esacerbato per via di contrasti precedenti, ma non nascondeva nessunissima intenzione xenofoba.

Per aggiungere qualcosa di positivo al tuo primo commento, @DaG, discutere quasi litigando, come tu hai detto, ma concentrandosi sugli argomenti di cui si parla può essere fonte di grande felicità. Per capire a cosa mi riferisco, consiglierei la lettura delle pagine 6-8 di questo articolo, in cui Wheeler parla di Bohr e di Einstein.

Cara Charo,
non penso che il problema sia dovuto al fatto che tu sia donna, ma al fatto che il sito abbia poche domande (e di conseguenza anche poche risposte), per cui le tue risaltano.
Su SE ci sono poche donne perché è nato come una piattaforma per programmatori, una professione tradizionalmente maschile (io ne so qualcosa, quando ho iniziato questo lavoro, trent'anni fa, sono stata una delle prime donne a farlo nella mia azienda).
Sono d'accordissimo sul fatto di non dover sempre citare le fonti. Per esempio, io sono milanese, se dicessi che a Milano si usa mettere l'articolo davanti ai nomi propri (in italiano corretto non si fa) e mi chiedessero di citare la fonte, li manderei a quel paese.
Quello che ho notato anch'io, su tutta SE, è che alcuni utenti tendono a diventare la "casta" del sito e se uno osa esprimere delle opinioni contrarie alle loro viene massacrato.
Su TeX.SE, ad esempio, ho sollevato delle critiche e sono stata accusata di pensare che il sito sia mio e di voler imporre le mie regole. 
A seguito di ciò e di altri episodi in cui non mi sono trovata d'accordo con alcune (in)azioni dei moderatori (di TeX.SE), ho limitato molto la mia partecipazione.
Il mio consiglio è: fai quello che ritieni giusto e non ti preoccupare di cosa dicono gli altri. 
Dato che siamo sul sito della lingua italiana, ti cito il Sommo Poeta: 

non ragioniam di lor, ma guarda e passa.

Un caro saluto!
Carla

Grazie mille di questo tuo post, Carla! Bellissime, come sempre, le parole di Dante (Virgilio). Lo farò, puoi esserne sicura. Accade che, in questi ultimi giorni, è diventato troppo difficile per me essere moderatrice e utente del sito allo stesso tempo. E adesso ho bisogno di riposarmi.

Può darsi che tutto questo non sia stato per il fatto di essere donna, ma ti posso assicurare che molte delle cose che mi sono state dette sono per il fatto di non essere italiana. E, a un certo punto, ho avuto la forte impressione che qualcuno avesse identificato la mia persona con un essere debole e che mi si volesse far sentir stupida (non ho riportato alcuni dei commenti che vanno in questo senso).  Come hai probabilmente notato, ho già seguito la massima di Dante-Virgilio in certo modo: non ho parlarto di persone, ma di fatti.

@Charo Purtroppo l'odio per il diverso sta crescendo in tutti gli ambiti, in tutto il mondo, probabilmente fomentato o giustificato da chi riceve una qualche convenienza politica da ciò. In Italia ci odiamo persino tra di noi (Nord vs. Sud, ma non solo, per es. Pisa vs. Livorno). Quello che ti consiglio è di ignorare le persone che ti insultano, non solo qui, in generale, è il modo migliore per combatterle.

Grazie mille, Carla! Puoi esserne sicura: lo farò. Purtroppo, quello che hai spiegato succede anche nel mio paese. Tra l'altro, è stata una delle cause di una guerra e di una dettatura, e i vincitori di quella guerra sono ancora ben vivi. A differenza di quello che è accaduto in altri paesi d'Europa, qui veramente non si è detto mai basta a tutto questo.

E, per favore, non criticare i moderatori di questo sito. Posso assicurarvi che hanno fatto e faranno tutto quello che si deve fare. Ho detto di essere forte, ma probabilmente  non sarei sopravvissuta (in senso figurato: come utente e come moderatrice) senza di loro.

@Charo No, non criticavo i moderatori di questo sito, criticavo quelli di TeX.SE. :) L'ho specificato.

Charo, ti prego di non smettere di postare domande. Hanno dato a tanti (a me in primis) grande occasione di esplorare termini nuovi dei quali non ero a conoscenza. Questi atteggiamenti che citi sono nella migliore delle ipotesi consigli mal riposti ed al peggio bullismo a tutti gli effetti. 

Non ti preoccupare, @Easymode44: non smetterò di postare domande. È soltanto che ho dovuto prendermi un po' di riposo.

Rispondo perché è il posto giusto e il momento giusto, e perché sono stato
chiamato in causa molto direttamente.
Per me la tua domanda è completamente retorica: a me pare più che altro uno sfogo. Comunque
rispondo:

Credete che alcuno dei fatti che ho sopra descritto ... possa derivare in qualche sorta di barriera alla partecipazione?

Sì. Se, per esempio, mi venisse voglia di correggere tutti gli errori che trovo nei post ma, impossibilitato a farlo (per ragioni di reputazione insufficiente), riempissi il sito di commenti
come "correggi quest'errore", "la parola X si scrive così e non così" eccetera, si leverebbero non una ma più barriere: una per me, e una per i destinatari dei commenti. Ci sono comportamenti errati, comportamenti meno errati o quasi perfetti, e comportamenti perfetti; gli ultimi a volte sono irragiungibili.
Ma qualsiasi cosa tu faccia, ci sarà qualcuno che non è contento, e questo qualcuno ha il diritto di dirlo. In definitiva, la barriera che tu lamenti è dentro di te, e non sei la sola qui, perché la stessa cosa sta capitando a me.

credete che si dovrebbe cercare di rispettare la libertà di un utente di scegliere da sé le domande che vuol porre nel sito?

Sì. Ma come detto prima, chi non è d'accordo ha, a sua volta, la libertà di dire che non è d'accordo; può farlo in modo anonimo (e inutile secondo me) con i downvote, oppure in modo più costruttivo con i commenti, o meglio ancora scrivere in meta. Ma se lì (in meta) si ritrovano ancora quelle stesse barriere, siamo punto e a capo. E a questo proposito ribadisco che un voto negativo, sia su una domanda sia su una risposta, sia nel sito normale sia in meta, contribuisce comunque a erigere una barriera, a far passar la voglia di postare altro che commenti che non si possono downvotare e costringono i critici a esporsi. Il problema, e non sono io a dirlo, è che
un sottosito di stackexchange pieno di diatribe di commenti fa brutta figura; ma farebbe anche brutta figura senza commenti e con molte domande e risposte piene di downvote.
Insomma, hai scritto questa domanda per farti rispondere "brava Charo, hai ragione, hanno invece torto quei cattivoni di Linuxfan e Nico"? Eccoti servita: la tua domanda è marcata con +3, la risposta di Nico con -3, per la mia basta aspettare. La risposta di CarLatex, equilibrata e che condivido al 90% vince su tutte con il suo +4. Il 10% residuo, che condivido solo in parte, riguarda la citazione di Dante, e mi spiego.
In una situazione di contrasto verso il sito, come la mia e la tua, ci sono 3 possibili azioni: 1) adeguarsi,
ma questo è costoso e lascia sensi di colpa; 2) lasciare, ed è una sconfitta anche se ci si sente magari superiori; 3) continuare imperterriti come dice Dante, e anche questo è costoso. Io non sono per nulla sicuro che sia sempre la strada giusta, forse non per te e per me.
Ora devo fare alcune precisazioni, perché pare che io abbia criticato tutto quello che fai tu, ma questo è vero solo in parte: per esempio, se io critico chi usa molto l'automobile, e succede che tu lo fai tutti i giorni, puoi sentirti (giustamente) direttamente accusata. Ma io non ho criticato te, ho criticato tutti quelli che lo fanno, e la cosa è molto diversa. Naturalmente vedere te passarmi davanti in macchina
tutti i giorni scatena due cose: 1) che tu ti senti chiamata in causa, perché tu lo fai; e 2) che a me la cosa viene in mente
perché la vedo tutti i giorni. Questa è un'analogia per spiegare che impressione fa a me aprire la pagina delle domande e vedere il tuo nome ovunque. Il passo successivo è provare a immaginare l'impressione che fa a qualsiasi altra persona. E questi ragionamenti non li faccio perché tu mi stai antipatica, ma perché qualcuno (sempre tu, tra l'altro) dice in meta che ci sono poche domande, così io cerco di aiutare e dare le mie impressioni.
Veniamo quindi alla risposta che ho dato (We need more questions / Abbiamo bisogno di più domande),
e che tu hai citato estesamente. Forse hai citato tutti i miei pensieri come se fossero esclusivamente rivolti a te; io non voglio fare un poema e mi limiterò a chiarirne qualcuno, ricordando che ogni idea era espressa in un suo paragrafo, e il primo di questi diceva "Per rendere il sito più attrattivo e utile, e invogliare a usarlo di più, si potrebbe considerare alcune cose".

non scrivere una domanda a una mia risposta dopo che qualcun altro l'ha fatto

Io non ho scritto che tu non devi. Ho scritto "Attenzione a rispondere alle proprie domande",
spiegando poi la mia idea (su meta si esprimono le idee, giusto?). E soprattutto non ho scritto
"non te ne sei accorta che il motore del sito chiede 'sei sicuro..."; sei tu che, dentro di te, hai
inteso così: le mie parole erano a supporto del ragionamento generale.

citando il Garzanti ma potrebbe accadere che Garzanti non sia l'unico a pensarla a quel modo

Qui non ci siamo proprio capiti. Se io cito il Garzanti, e putacaso il Garzanti è sbagliato, allora
sono in errore anche io. Sicuramente una cosa la dimostro: che il Garzanti non è l'unico a dire una cosa,
perché quella cosa la sto dicendo anche io. Questo di nuovo è un ragionamento generale, logico, astratto, a
sostegno della criticità che esprimevo verso l'uso indiscriminato delle fonti, e non credo proprio
che tu, con la cura che metti nelle tue ricerche, dovresti sentirti toccata da questo ragionamento.

non citare nelle mie risposte soltanto libri colti scritti magari secoli fa

Ancora, non stavo parlando di te. Stavo notando quella che per me è una brutta abitudine dei dizionari,
di citare testi vecchi e famosi (o colti) che, basta leggerli, non rispecchiano l'italiano moderno,
parlato da milioni di persone. Ma lo stesso discorso vale quando citano Eco o Pirandello: gl'italiani
normali non parlano come loro. Voglio dire: hai preso come personale una critica rivolta a qualcun
altro.
Chiudo con un pensiero riguardo al fatto che tu sia donna e straniera. Io non credo che in questo sito
ci sia qualcuno che ti discrimina per essere spagnola, anzi - come forse non sai, generalmente agli
italiani gli spagnoli vanno a genio, senz'altro più di altri stranieri. Per il fatto di essere donna,
poi, credo a maggior ragione che tu non ti debba preoccupare. Hai citato:

women are more likely to ask questions, while men provide more answers and cast more votes.

Io ho una mia spiegazione per questo fatto, ma non la dirò perché è fuori tema. Mi limito a dire
che Madre Natura crea gli uomini diversi dalle donne, e ha o ha avuto ottimi motivi per farlo. Il progresso
sociale e scientifico hanno reso questi motivi obsoleti, ma uomini e donne continuano a essere diversi. E' un fatto genetico. Questa diversità si manifesta, per forza, ed è stancante sentire le donne che accusano gli uomini, la
società e quant'altro, come se la diversità fosse colpa loro.
Però questa citazione che hai fatto non si adatta a te, non si avvicina minimamente al tuo modo di agire, quindi non so
perché tu l'abbia riportata.
Voglio precisare ancora che io scrivo per aiutare questo sito, che per me è solo un passatempo, e per aiutare
te, perché mi stai simpatica. Fedele al mio stesso pensiero, riporto le mie idee e le mie impressioni; saranno
tutte sbagliate? Va bene lo stesso, io il mio contributo l'ho dato e penso che ora possa bastare. Tu e tutti
gli altri avete solo da scegliere dal menù (di cose ne ho dette anche troppe), se c'è qualcosa che vi piace
bene, altrimenti fa lo stesso per tutti. E faccio un paragone con quell'utente che, in risposta a "perché
le parole spagnole in italiano sono al plurale?", ha risposto che gli italiani pensano che per tradurre
in spagnolo basta aggiungere una "S" al fondo, e questo "potrebbe spiegare". Beh, naturalmente la risposta ha raggiunto il punteggio di
-3, ma io non la giudico così negativamente: ha fatto notare una cosa che esiste, e non ha affermato che
quella fosse LA spiegazione. La risposta successiva, con punteggio di +4, mi pare altrettanto infondata.
Ma voi spagnoli parlate sempre al plurale? Direi proprio di no! La risposta finiva citando la parola "media"
con il suo plurale latino: è vero, ma c'è il piccolo particolare che la parola ci è arrivata dall'inglese.
Insomma, per me quella è una cattiva risposta; io ho letto da qualche parte che i prestiti dallo spagnolo sono un'eccezione.
Però non trovo più il libro, e allora in quella discussione mi sono limitato a scrivere un commento. Perché avevo paura a scrivere una risposta in competizione con una votata a +4".

Come da aspettarsi cominciano i downvote anonimi che riequilibro con  un upvote per un semplice ma essenziale motivo. Nel tuo post dai atto dello spirito critico che chi ha lasciato in eredità l'Illuminismo e che consiste nell'esporre dettagliatamente i propri argomenti e nel motivare i punti su cui non si concorda. Qui il criticare viene concepito da diversi nella sua accezione quotidiana di parlare male di qualcuno o di attaccarlo. Non devi avere paura se ti va di scrivere qualcosa perché così facendo ti privi dei diritti che ti spettano per democrazia (lemma poco conosciuto anch'esso qui).

Mi riaggancio qui per farti vedere come il bashing sia sistematico https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11613/does-italian-have-a-demonstrative-pronoun-for-2nd-person

"Tessere" implica un complotto premedetitato, cosa che qui non ha senso. "Giorno della donna" etc non c'entra nulla con questo, ma è solo un pretesto per atteggiarsi a vittima. Tu non sei vittima di nessuno né perché donna o straniera, ma vieni criticata per come ti poni qui (e non sono il solo ad aver cercato di fartelo capire). Di obiettività e di autoriflessione questo post non ha nulla di nulla. 

Ho downvotato perché questo post non ha un tono gentile.

Ne hai tutti i diritti.

Anche a me non è piaciuto il legame di Charo tra lamentele legittime - essere stranieri - giorno della donna. E non mi è piaciuto vedere quattro voti negativi sul tuo post. Penso che downvotare i post su meta non colga lo spirito di meta stesso; i voti qui non servono per far capire a tutti gli utenti quanto pregio e autorità una risposta abbia; per me qui tutte le risposte hanno pari dignità e un downvote equivale a un insulto. E invito chi a questo proposito cita le regole di SE, a ragionarci sopra.

@linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Come avevi scritto tu, certi atteggiamenti fanno scemare la voglia di partecipare (e io sto raggiungendo un "point of no return", il che sicuramente non dispiacerà alla maggioranza). Qui molti sembrano dimenticare che chi contribuisce lo fa nel suo tempo libero, con buone intenzioni e con uno spirito di comunità (che a me pare non esistere). Essere redarguiti senza che si siano usate parole offensive e assistere contemporaneamente all'approvazione di titoli indirizzati a me quali "troll" (con tanto di upvotes), la dice lunga. Ripeto, un peso e due misure.
